# Subclassed ListView column 0 displays corrupted text on Windows 7

Tags: winforms

Windows 7 (64 bit), .NET 4 (32 bit app)

I have a subclassed System.Windows.Forms.ListView comprising 2 columns displayed 
in "Details" view.  Only text fields are involved.  The list comprises about 100 
rows.  On initial display all fields are drawn clearly but when scrolling or 
"paging" with the scroll bar the text of some fields in the first column becomes 
unreadable.  It appears to be overwriten with random lines and blotches.

Is there anything that I can do to ensure that the text is clearly drawn in column 0?

The effect is diminished (clarity improved) when using remote desktop across a 
LAN.
The effect disappears (all text is drawn clearly) when using remote desktop 
across a WAN.

The ListView has always drawn perfectly on Windows XP.

For the purposes of a stripped down test, column header and DrawItem calls are ingored.  The problem area is OnDrawSubItem which comprises the code

```
protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap))
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left
          ,e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black
          ,rect, sf);
    }
    base.OnDrawSubItem(e);
}
```

The following is the complete code that reproduces the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
///
/// Build by saving to a file called LVTrial.cs and then executing "csc LVTrial.cs"
/// Scroll list up and down on a windows 7 box and the first column of text is corrupted.
///

class MyListView : ListView
{
    Random randomiser = new Random();
    private const int NUM_ROWS = 100;
    private const int NUM_COLS = 2;
    public MyListView()
    {
        this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 25);
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(625, 387);
        this.TabIndex = 0;
        this.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        for (int ii = 0; ii < NUM_COLS; ii++)
        {
            this.Columns.Add((
              (System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader())));
        }
        for (int ii = 0; ii < NUM_ROWS; ii++)
        {
            this.Items.Add( new ListViewItem( 
              new string[NUM_COLS] { CreateRandomString(1, 6), CreateRandomString(1, 6) } ) );
        }
    }
    protected override void OnDrawSubItem(DrawListViewSubItemEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap))
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left
              ,e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.SubItem.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black
              ,rect, sf);
        }
        base.OnDrawSubItem(e);
    }
    private string CreateRandomString(int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        int length = randomiser.Next(minLength, maxLength + 1);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < length; ii++)
        {
            int asciiChar = randomiser.Next(32, 126);   // ascii range
            str += Convert.ToChar(asciiChar);
        }
        return str;
    }
}

class LVTrial : Form
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new LVTrial());
    }
    private LVTrial()
    {
        MyListView myListView = new MyListView();
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(674, 440);
        this.Controls.Add(myListView);
        this.Text = "LVTrial";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recorded this as a Windows 7 bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657909/subclassed-listview-column-0-displays-corrupted-text-on-windows-7

My own workaround for the problem was to insert an additional column at position 0.  I now draw a rectangle with a transparent brush in column 0 for each item.  All of which stops the text in the column to the right being drawn corrupt.  I imagine drawing an image would achieve the same thing but I have not tried it.  You can't hide this dummy column as the problem simply transfers to the second column (i.e. the first visible coolumn).

Another tip is that it seems to be performance related.  The bug was more likely to occur with 100 items in the list view than 10,000.